# How to fix "Error unmarshalling response back from AWS, Response Body: Unknown error" in x.io using Unity AWS SDK for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-dynamodb

I developed `DynamoDB` Tables for my application using unity `SDK`. Authentication is done using `Cognito` identities. When trying to read/write values to a table it is working in my local machine. But when the application is hosted in `x.io`  I get an error.

I am not able to figure out the issue. There are not many resources to debug this error.

```cs
public void PostUserAccountDetails(UserAccounts userInfo)
        {
            DbContext.LoadAsync<UserAccounts>(userInfo.mailID, (result) =>
                 {
                     if (result.Exception == null)
                     {
                         var user = result.Result as UserAccounts;
                         Debug.Log(user == null ? true : false);
                         if (user == null)
                         {
                             Debug.Log("mail id is new");
                             signupText.text = "The mail id has never been used before";
                             DbContext.SaveAsync<UserAccounts>(userInfo, (res) =>
                            {
                                if (res.Exception == null)
                                {
                                    Debug.Log("signed up successfully");
                                    signupText.text = "signed up successfully";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Debug.Log("error while signing up");
                                    signupText.text = "error while signing up";
                                }
                            });
                        }
                         else
                         {
                             Debug.Log("This mail id has already been used");
                             signupText.text = "This mail id has already been used";
                         }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         Debug.Log(result.Exception.Message);
                         signupText.text = result.Exception.Message;
                     }
                 });
        }
```

I get the error message

```
"Error unmarshalling response back from AWS, Response Body: Unknown error"
```